# How do I filter data between multiple columns into new columns after INNER JOINS?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Brand new to SQL, so apologies that I don't really know how to word the question or find an existing answer. Let me explain further. I'm creating a Chat app for fun with a DM system. I have a table (dms_history) setup that has a row gen. for every new distinct chat between 2 users w/ the last DM being sent between the 2 users. eg:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    uid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    pid VARCHAR(40),
    uname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    email valid_email,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);

CREATE TABLE dms (
    dmid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    uid INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(uid),
    recip INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(uid),
    msg TEXT NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);

-- TABLE I'M TALKING ABOUT
CREATE TABLE dms_history (
    user1 INT REFERENCES users(uid),
    user2 INT REFERENCES users(uid),
    last_dm INT REFERENCES dms(dmid),
    PRIMARY KEY(user1, user2),
    CHECK (user1 < user2)
);
```

Say I'm trying to get all the data w/ joins on this table (dms_history) for client user uid#2. eg:

```
SELECT
    u1.uid as u1id,
    u1.uname as u1name,
    u2.uid as u2id,
    u2.uname as u2name,
    dms.dmid,
    dms.msg
FROM dms_history h
INNER JOIN users u1 ON h.user1 = u1.uid
INNER JOIN users u2 ON h.user2 = u2.uid
INNER JOIN dms ON h.last_dm = dms.dmid
WHERE u1.uid = 2 OR u2.uid = 2;
```

That query I thought of is close to what I want, *but what I really want* is only to show the user opposite of the client user being queried (so NOT user uid#2 alice) along w/ the last message sent. How do I filter or UNION? those columns into a new column. Picture to explain what I want:

[image: Example of what I want; how do I filter columns?]

Think of Twitter DMs and how it shows the users you're DMing and a snippet of the last message sent.
Apologies if I did a poor job explaining, it's not my strong suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more reading the past few hours I found I could use subqueries with SELECTs and UNIONs to achieve what I was after. Not sure how efficient it is, but it works.

```
WITH chats AS (SELECT * FROM dms_history h WHERE h.user1 = 2 OR h.user2 = 2)
SELECT
    chats2.user1 as recip_id,
    u.uname as recip_uname,
    chats2.last_dm as dmid,
    dms.msg,
    dms.created_at
FROM (
    SELECT chats.user1, chats.last_dm FROM chats
    UNION
    SELECT chats.user2, chats.last_dm FROM chats
) AS chats2
INNER JOIN users u ON chats2.user1 = u.uid
INNER JOIN dms ON chats2.last_dm = dms.dmid
WHERE chats2.user1 != 2;
```